# ratelimit in django giving error Key 'rl:xxxx' not found

Tags: python, django, rate-limiting

I am trying to use ratelimit in my Django site to restrict the number of requests from one **IP** in some time. Following is what I am trying.

urls.py

```
url(r'^test/$', 'myapp.views.test', name='myapp.views.test'),
```

views.py

```
@ratelimit(key='ip', rate='5/m')
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("Request submitted successfully.")
```

When I am trying to hit the url - http://:8080/test/ it is giving me the following error.

> ValueError at /test/
>
> Key 'rl:bbbcf11eb514e3e14d9472f112fc06b0' not found
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://:8080/test/ Django
>   Version:  1.6 Exception Type:     ValueError Exception Value:
>
> Key 'rl:bbbcf11eb514e3e14d9472f112fc06b0' not found

I am trying to use document at - http://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

There is something regarding setting `RATELIMIT_USE_CACHE` in settings.py, but not sure what should be set in this setting. I am relatively new to the Django

Answer (score 0):

Seems that ratelimit needs to use the [Django Cache Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) to store the information about IPs and requests.

You'll need to setup some sort of cache, preferably memcached to use it. Hope that helps!